# Resize column width in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to resize column width in bootstrap.
Curently, I have 3 `<div>` with `col-md-4`. But when one of the `<div>` hides then I want to change another 2 `<div>'s` into `col-md-6`.

Is this possible in bootstrap?

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="col-md-4">

           </div>
                <div id="txthide">
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>          
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>
```